# Cordova and SwipeRefreshLayout Android Lollipop feature

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, android-5.0-lollipop, crosswalk-runtime

I have just released an update for my cordova/crosswalk app to support `Android Lollipop 5.1.x`.
I have noticed that when I swipe down in any view of my app a refresh button comes down (`SwipeRefreshLayout` new feature).

The problem is that after that the app becomes all white blank.

I there a way to handle that button with javascript or to disable it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I made an Android Application on Polymer for version above 4.0.x, It worked fine on SwipeRefresh you need to wait for some time may be you are facing connectivity isssue.

at mine end it worked fine.

Comment: You not answer the question

Comment: Thanks, but it does not help me with the answer